# Unable to insert a 4000 characters string into a varchar2(4000) column

Tags: postgresql, oracle, azure-data-factory, etl

I have a simple Azure Data Factory pipeline.

This pipeline has a single activity, a copy activity, that:

- reads a table from a PostgreSQL database
- writes the data to an identical table in an Oracle database

The table has a very large column named "MyColumn" with the following types:

- `character varying(4000)` in Postgresql
- `varchar2(4000)` in Oracle

Sometimes the pipeline fails on the sink side (Oracle) side with this error:

> "Operation on target Populate staging failed: Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Invalid precision value. Error in parameter 52.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.Exceptions.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Invalid precision value. Error in parameter 52.,Source=msora28.dll,'"

After a good deal of tests I noticed that the pipeline fails only if the table contains at least one row having "MyColumn" filled up with all the 4000 available characters.

So if any of the rows has column "MyColumn" completely filled with 4000 characters, then the pipeline fails, whereas if "MyColumn" contains 3999 (or less) characters for all the rows, then the pipeline works.

I already tried the following:

- executed the same insert operation (with 4000 characters in "MyColumn") directly in an  Oracle client and, of course, this worked
- executed the same insert operation (with 4000 characters in "MyColumn") in ADF using a script activity, and this worked. This means that the problem only occurs in a copy activity
- disabled the "staging" option in the copy activity, to no avail

Can you share any experience/insights on similar issues?

Comment: In Oracle, a `VARCHAR2` is limited to 4000 BYTES (unless you are on a later version and have told it to use extended strings). If you have multi-byte characters in your string then you will not be able to store 4000 CHARACTERS.

Comment: Does your problematic 4000-character string have any multibyte characters? On the Oracle side you are limited to 4000 *bytes* even with char semantics (i.e. `varchar2(4000 char)`) - so you can't necessarily store 4000 characters. I believe PostgreSQL doesn't have that distinction here.

Comment: Encoding differences?

Comment: @MT0, Alex Poole, your comments are very on spot: I also thought about multibyte characters, so I tried to transfer a single row with that column filled up with 4000 characters 'a', but I got the same error.

Comment: That seems unlikely.

Comment: @Zegarek as you can read in the last part of my question a direct insert in an Oracle client and an insert using a script activity in ADF both work. What does not work is the same thing performed using an ADF copy activity.

Comment: What character set are you using in PostgreSQL and in Oracle? If you are using a multi-byte character set in PostgreSQL and a single-byte character set in Oracle then you might implicitly be trying to copy more than 4000 bytes of data if it just does a straight byte-for-byte copy rather than converting between character sets.

Comment: In that case I would speculate (even more) that at some point it's being treated as a  null-temrinated string. If you look at a 3999 character value that is copied successfully, what do `length()` and `lengthb()` report for it, and if you `dump()` it (or the last few characters of it) does it show a nul (chr 0) at then end?

Comment: @Andrea You're right, my apologies. What Oracle version is this?

Comment: @Zegarek no worries! This is the version: "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production"

Comment: @AlexPoole `length()` returns 3999, `lengthb()` returns 3999, `dump(MyColumn)` returns 'Typ=1 Len=3999: 50,83...'

Comment: OK. Searching for the 'invalid precision value' gives results suggesting a problem with the ODBC driver or binding (which may be hidden in the copy action I guess). I don't know anything about this set-up really, but based on some of those links (e..g [this](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Desktop-Discussions/Invalid-precision-value-inserting-into-sql-varchar-max/td-p/56928)), can you use an OLEDB driver instead? Anyway, as it doesn't seem to be a problem  with Oracle I'm out of ideas, but good luck.